# how can i display arabic text in google map info-window?

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to display arabic text on google map info-window, each with their own infowindow.

```
 Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
         .title(companyName).snippet(companyName));

       CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();

       googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
       googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
       googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
       googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

       marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? So long as `companyName` is in Arabic, and so long as the device locale is set to be Arabic, I would expect the info window to render Arabic text.

Answer (score 4):

that so simple for rtl language's
of course i think that's bug when you write .title("عربی") android show blank infowindow.
but you should use this command
.title("\u200e"+"عربی")

Comment: Working for me, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem.  I just discovered that the Google Maps Android SDK 2.0 marker information window is blank if the language on the device is set to Arabic, Hebrew, Persian, or Urdu (i.e. a right to left language) and the passed string is in the same language.  I have checked this with Android Studio to make sure that the string is in the correct language.  The value of the string is correct when stopped at a breakpoint in AS but not in the information window on the device (the window is blank).  It may have something to do with my particular device not fully supporting those languages, or it may be a bug in the SDK (or both).

Comment: Update: I tested some of my other apps and they are able to display strings in "right to left" languages correctly, so the above problem is probably caused by a bug in the Google Maps Android SDK.